# Query IEnumerable<XObject> containing unknown elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am looking to query an IEnumerable to filter it based on attributes held in the lower elements. I don't know the element names but do know the attributes to query.

To give more details.

This SearchVars class will contain selected search options on a form. It also contains a property for ObjectType which is the identifier for which XML objects are in the file. for the below XML example Object Type would be T1

```
    class SearchVars
    {
      public string  ObjectType { get; set; }
      public string ClientId  { get; set; }
      public string CustRef { get; set; }
    }
```

An Example XML Extract

```
<root>
<T1>
    <FT ClientID="PCL1" />
    <T2 CustRef="Cust1">
        <T3 Name="Site1">
            <TER Error="123" ErrorText="Error 123" />
            <TER Error="234" ErrorText="Error 234" />
            <T4 SubErr="50420208">
                <TSER ID="2199991741074" CHN="1">
                    <TER Error="567" ErrorText="Error 567" />
                </TSER>
            </T4>
        </T3>
    </T2>
</T1>
<T1>
    <FT ClientID="PCL1" />
    <T2 CustRef="Cust2">
        <T3 Name="Site2">
            <TER Error="123" ErrorText="Error 123" />
            <TER Error="234" ErrorText="Error 234" />
        </T3>
    </T2>
</T1>
</root>
```

I would be trying to search for Error attributes based on ClientID's and CustRef's. In the search method my initial code is to pull all the T1's into an enumerable.  the 2 empty IFs is where I will have LINQ queries filtering the data on the search variable. So if ClientID is PCL1, filter the T1s where that client ID attribute value is present.

```
         public static IEnumerable<XObject> PerformSearch(string xmlData, Models.SearchVars vars)
         {
           XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
           IEnumerable<XObject> result = document.Descendants(vars.ObjectType);

           if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(vars.ClientId))
           {


           }

           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vars.CustRef))
           {

           }

           return result;
         }
```

I hope what I am attempting is clear and looking forward to learning a little today. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not as clean a solution as I would like, but it works. Very much open to better ideas!

```
class Search
{
    public static IEnumerable<XObject> PerformSearch(string xmlData, Models.SearchVars vars)
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
        IEnumerable<XObject> result = document.Descendants(vars.ObjectType);

        if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(vars.ClientId))
        {
            result = from i in result
                     where i.ToString().Contains(string.Format("ClientId={0}",vars.ClientId))
                     select i;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vars.CustRef))
        {
            result = from i in result
                     where i.ToString().Contains(string.Format("CustRef={0}", vars.CustRef))
                     select i;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```